# Codeignighter - Undefined variable in the view

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller

I have been scratching my head for a while on this one,

```
public function business()
    {
    $org = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['org_id'];
    $query['org_details'] = $this->business_model->org_account($org);   
    $data = array('navigationContent' => $this->load->view('parts/p_navigation', array(), TRUE), 'mainContent' => $this->load->view('platform/business', array(), TRUE),);
    $this->load->view('templates/platform', $data, $query);
    }
```

Produces this error `Undefined variable: org_details` in the view. I can't work out why this does not work

EDIT THE VIEW As Requested

```
<?php foreach($org_details as $row): ?>
        <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Platform Company ID:</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="<?= $row['org_id']?>" disabled>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">ABN:</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="<?= $row['org_abn']?>" disabled>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Business Name:</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="<?= $row['org_name']?>" disabled>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Address:</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="<?= $row['org_address']?>" disabled>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Suburb:</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="<?= $row['org_suburb']?>" disabled>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">State:</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="<?= $row['org_state']?>" disabled>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Post Code:</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="<?= $row['org_pcode']?>" disabled>
        </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I have updated the controller as the answeres have come in and still having the same result

Comment: include the view in your question as well

Comment: You are loading three different views, and you aren't passing the `org_details` data item to any of them. And the third parameter of `$this->load->view()` is a boolean for whether or not to return the content as a string.

Comment: i think your model does not return any data....$query['org_details'] = $this->business_model->org_account($org);...try print_r($query['org_details']); is it showing something???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
'mainContent' => $this->load->view('platform/business', $query, TRUE),);
```

By a pure fluke this works!

Comment: It's not a fluke -- before you were not passing this data to your view at all. Now you are.

Answer (score 1):

pass `org_details` in data array since the `load->view` accept only two parrameters..

> Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the second parameter of the view loading function.

```
public function business()
{
   $org = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['org_id'];
   $data['org_details'] = $this->business_model->org_account($org);   
   $data ['navigationContent']=$this->load->view('parts/p_navigation', array(), TRUE);
   $data['mainContent'] = $this->load->view('platform/business', array(), TRUE);
   $this->load->view('templates/platform', $data);
}
```

[docs here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Comment: check if you are getting values here  first `$this->business_model->org_account($org);`...

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your model code

```
    $this->business_model->org_account($org);
```

may b model it not returning a result();